# Exportar tabla mysql en CSV

Tags: mysql, csv

Estoy intentando exportar una tabla de mysql a csv. Esto ya lo he conseguido pero en el archivo csv no aparecen los campos de las columnas exportadas.

El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

`select Nombre,Direccion INTO OUTFILE 'prueba.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que exporte también los nombres de las columnas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu query usas `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'`

```
select Nombre, Direccion INTO OUTFILE 'prueba.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

si deseas crear un archivo .CSV por [definición](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) debes usar principalmente `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

el query quedaría de esta forma :

```
(SELECT 'Nombre', 'Direccion') 
UNION ALL
(SELECT Nombre, Direccion INTO OUTFILE 'prueba.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```

Answer (score 4):

Para obtener los nombres de las columnas en tu csv debes usar UNION.

Prueba intentando lo siguiente:

```
(SELECT 'Nombre','Direccion')
UNION 
(SELECT Nombre,Direccion
FROM tu_tabla
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n');
```